# How to resolve domain name from public IP on Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have just created my aws instance on windows server 2012 R2 for running my website. Problem is, i want to resolve my public IP address to my domain name.For example, my aws public IP address is 1.2.3.4 and i want it to show as my own company domain

Comment: are you really asking for reverse DNS (1.2.3.4 to domain.com) or do you mean normal forward DNS (domain.com to 1.2.3.4)?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may seem strange because of the way it works, but it is from an official source and it does accomplish what you want -- setting a reverse DNS record on an elastic IP address.  The address will remain associated with your account and can't be inadvertently released unless you subsequently undo this configuration.

> You can now provide us with a configurable Reverse DNS record for any of your Elastic IP addresses. Once you’ve supplied us with the record, reverse DNS lookups (from IP address to domain name) will work as expected: the Elastic IP address in question will resolve to the domain that you specified in the record.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses

You'll be sending a request to AWS support to configure this mapping.

The unexpected part of the solution, however, is the *reason* stated on the form that you use to send the request to AWS support...

https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

...it's actually the request form to remove the outbound SMTP port 25 restriction on your Elastic IPs... but part of the process is to assign reverse DNS entries to EIPs that you specify.